# How do I prevent textarea maxlength from blocking submit

Tags: html, textarea

I set a maxlength on the textarea field. How do I prevent maxlength from blocking submit in cases where the user goes above the maxlength of the textarea?

Comment: You can implement any plausibility checks you like using JavaScript on the client site.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean: I think what you meant to say is "How do I block submit if..." instead of "... prevent it ...", because maxlength on textarea has no effect, unless you have some sort of client side validation which you haven't told us about.

Comment: On submit you can just check the length of the input string and in case its longer than your preset limit just return false to stop the submit action

Comment: You should keep a server side check, else, nothing is secure, you use `maxlength` I will remove the attribute and post the form, you use JS and I will disable JS so use server side check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using Javascript / jQuery. Check the length of your text area, and if it is more that what you want(maxt length) give an alert and do not allow to submit the form.

```
<script>
    function formSubmit(){
        var count = $("#your_textarea").val().length;
        if(count >= MAX_LENGHT) {
            alert("Max length reached for the text area");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<textarea id="your_textarea"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="formSubmit()" value="Submit form">

note: codes are not tested.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope Below code help you.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function test()
{
    var txtval_length=document.getElementById("txt").value.length;
    if(txtval_length>30)  // here 30 is temporary purpose you can set as per your requirement.
    {
        return false; // do not allow to submit
    }
    else
    {
        return true; //  submit form
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test1.html" method="post" onsubmit="return test();">
    <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In above example if the length of **textarea** character is less then 30 then it allow to submit form otherwise form will not submit. you can change condition as per your requirements.